# Prove equivalence of definitions of density

Tags: analysis

We are trying to work through the following question from a previous qualifying exam.

> Show that the following are equivalent for a subset $E$ of the set
>   $(0,1)$:
>
> 1. for all $x,y \in (0,1)$ with $x<y$ there exists $z \in E$ such that $x<z<y$,
> 2. every point of $(0,1)$ is a point of $E$ or a limit point of $E$.

We have started with the $2 \Rightarrow 1$ direction. We consider a point $z \in E$ then since $E \subset (0,1)$, $z \in (0,1)$. Since  $(0,1)$ is open, there exists an open ball $B_r(z) \subset (0,1)$.

We are getting stuck with how to proceed from here if it is even right.

Also, the other direction, we do not have any ideas.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: For the direction you are dealing with, suppose $0\lt x\lt y\lt 1$. If there is no $z\in E$ between $x$ and $y$, then $\frac{x+y}{2}$ is not in $E$ and is not a limit point of $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2. implies 1., you would start by fixing an $x\in (0,1)$ and a $y\in (0,1)$ with $y>x$. You need to show the existence of  the required $z$. (If the midpoint of $x$ and $y$ is in $E$, you're done. If not, by 2., there is a sequence from $E$ that converges to the midpoint. This will give you what you want.)

For 1. implies 2., pick a point $z\in (0,1)$. If $z\in E$, you're done. If not, you need to show $z$ is a limit point of $E$. In this case, select a sequence $y_n$ from $(0,1)$ that converges monotonically to $z$. Apply 1. to each pair $z, y_n$. Show this sequence gives you what you want.